# Comparing values of two dicts in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, loops, dictionary, for-loop

I have 2 dictionaries:

```
budgets = {'Engineering': 4500.0,
 'Marketing': 5000.0,
 'Operations': 3000.0,
 'Sales': 2000.0}

spending = {'Engineering': 5020.0,
 'Marketing': 1550.0,
 'Operations': 3670.0,
 'Sales': 3320.0}
```

I'm trying to loop through them each and find out which values in `spending` are greater than the values in `budgets`. I currently have written:

```
for value in spending.values():
    if value in spending.values() > budgets.values():
        print 'Over Budget'
    else:
        print 'Under Budget'
```

However when I run this, they all print `Over Budget` which clearly isn't the case. Can someone please explain my error in approaching this?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The section `value in spending.values() > budgets.values()` actually evaluates the boolean query `value in spending.values()`--a membership check--then compares the result of that to `budget.values()`: the values from `budget`. In Python, everything can be compared, so you compare the boolean to the list--the same thing every time, which in your case evaluates to `True`. What you'd want is more like this:

```
for key in spending:
    if spending[key] > budgets[key]:
        print('Over Budget')
    else:
        print('Under Budget')
```

EDIT: This pertains to Python 2 only. In Python 3, you get `TypeError: unorderable types`, which keeps you safe from mistakes like this.

Comment: I upvoted, but you should mention this is specific to Python 2. In Python 3, most inter-type comparisons give an error.

Comment: Good point. I assumed Python 2 since he's using `print` statements, sans parentheses.

Comment: Yes. Indeed it is tagged Python 2.7

Answer (score 2):

How about using `dict.items()`:

```
budgets = {'Engineering': 4500.0,
 'Marketing': 5000.0,
 'Operations': 3000.0,
 'Sales': 2000.0}

spending = {'Engineering': 5020.0,
 'Marketing': 1550.0,
 'Operations': 3670.0,
 'Sales': 3320.0}

for category, spent in spending.items():
    print(category)
    if spent > budgets[category]:
        print('Over Budget')
    else:
        print('Under Budget')
```

Answer (score 1):

@aryamccarthy has a great answer, but for Python's sake, I'll post another approach you could take, using only one line:

```
{(sk, 'Over Budget') if sv > budgets[sk] 
       else (sk, 'Under Budget') for sk, sv in spending.items()}
```

This approach returns the following, which isn't necessarily the prettiest way of displaying information, but it's not very far to get to pretty output using `print` from here:

```
{('Marketing', 'Under Budget'), ('Sales', 'Over Budget'), ('Engineering', 'Over Budget'), ('Operations', 'Over Budget')}
```

Note that this will raise a `KeyError` in the case of any key in `spending` not also belonging to `budgets`.

Comment: That's not *really* one line :P

Answer (score 0):

`if value in spending.values() > budgets.values():` supposed to be `value in spending.values():`

```
for value in spending.values():
   v={k:v for (k,v) in budgets.items() if v > value}
   if v:
      print "Under"
   else:
      print value, "is spending greater than the values in budget"
```

Comment: That condition is not doing what it should do. Your condition is pretty much doing something like `5000 > [5000.0, 2000.0, 4500.0, 3000.0]`. This is not correct.